# Unix shell script Or operator to delete fnix

Tags: unix

I want to delete `.txt` and `.csv` files from a particular folder. Below is  the shell script I am using. But its not deleting the files, if I use only of the file extension then it works. Can you please help here. I also used `||`, but did not work.

```
function purge_inbox_donefile(){
 cd $INBOX_DIR
 find . -path "*/done*" -iname ["*.txt" -o "*.csv"]  -exec rm -f {} \; -print
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `-o` between `-iname` parameters rather than within the pattern.  Such as:

```
-iname "*.txt" -o -iname "*.csv"
```

If you need to bracket your expression to keep it distinct from your other parameters, do not forget to escape your brackets, ie:

```
\( -iname "*.txt" -o -iname "*.csv" \)
```

Comment: Also note that `find` has the `-delete` flag

Comment: And using `cd` within the function instead of passing the directory to `find` is inelegant and potentially problematic.

Comment: @borrible ,I tried the script -iname "*.txt" -o -iname "*.csv" , but its deleting only one type of file( either .csv or .txt), but my folder has both files and I want to delete all files with these extension

Comment: @Swanand, go in to the directory that contains the file and try `find . \( -iname '*.txt' -o -iname '*.csv' \)` and see if you're getting all the files listed.  If you are (which should be the case, it's certainly what I see on my own setup) then you've an issue with the rest of your script.